# How to extract elements from html with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, voip

I am beginning to learn python and would like to try to use BeautifulSoup to extract the elements in the below html.

This html is taken from a voice recording system that logs the time and date in local time, UTC, call duration, called number, name, calling number, name, etc
There are usually hundreds of these entries.

What I am attempting to do is extract the elements and print them in one line to a comma delimited format in order to compare with call detail records from call manager.  This will help to verify that all calls were recorded and not missed.

I believe BeautifulSoup is the right tool to do this.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

```html
<tbody>
   <tr class="formRowLight">

<td class="formRowLight" >24/10/16<br>16:24:47</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >24/10/16 07:24:47</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >00:45</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >31301</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >Joe Smith</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >31111</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >Jane Doe</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >N/A</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >1432875648934</td>
<td align="center" class"formRowLight">&nbsp;</td>

   <tr class="formRowLight">

<td class="formRowLight" >24/10/16<br>17:33:02</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >24/10/16 08:33:02</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >00:58</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >35664</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >Billy Bob</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >227045665</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >James Dean</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >N/A</td>
<td class="formRowLight" >9934959586849</td>
<td align="center" class"formRowLight">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Yes, bs4 is a good tool to reach for to do this task. When you say `print them in one line` Do you mean you want ***all*** of the information printed on a single line? Just the text in each tag? Do you want to separate rows, or just have all the data together? A little more clarification on the expected output would be helpful. Also: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I looking to get something like this:  24/10/16 17:33:02, 24/10/16 08:33:02, 00:58,  35664, Billy Bob, 227045665,James Dean,N/A,9934959586849       I have tried some code at work but didnt achieve the results I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) would make things much easier - it would convert your tabular data from the HTML table into a [*dataframe*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) which, if needed, you can later [dump into CSV](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Here is a sample code to get you started:

```
import pandas as pd

data = """
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="formRowLight">
            <td class="formRowLight">24/10/16<br>16:24:47</td>
            <td class="formRowLight">Joe Smith</td>
            <td class="formRowLight">1432875648934</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="formRowLight">
            <td class="formRowLight">24/10/16<br>17:33:02</td>
            <td class="formRowLight">Billy Bob</td>
            <td class="formRowLight">9934959586849</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>"""

df = pd.read_html(data)[0]
print(df.to_csv(index=False))
```

Prints:

```
Date,Name,ID
24/10/1616:24:47,Joe Smith,1432875648934
24/10/1617:33:02,Billy Bob,9934959586849
```

FYI, `read_html()` actually uses `BeautifulSoup` to parse HTML under-the-hood.

Comment: No, but this would more likely to be comment than an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests

request = urllib2.Request(your url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(response)

mylist = []
div = soup.findAll('tr', {"class":"formRowLight"})
for line in div:
    text= video.findNext('td',{"class":"formRowLight"}).text
    mylist.append(text)

print mylist
```

But you need to edit this code a litt to prevent any duplicated content.

Comment: why would this produce duplicated results?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BeautifulSoup is a good tool to reach for in this problem. Something to get you started would be as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("my_log.html") as log_file:
    html = log_file.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html) 
#normally you specify a parser too `(html, 'lxml')` for example
#without specifying a parser, it will warn you and select one automatically

table_rows = soup.find_all("tr") #get list of all <tr> tags
for row in table_rows:
    table_cells = row.find_all("td") #get list all <td> tags in row
    joined_text = ",".join(cell.get_text() for cell in table_cells)
    print(joined_text)
```

However, `pandas`'s `read_html` may make this a bit more seamless, as mentioned in another answer to this question. Arguably `pandas` may be a better hammer to hit this nail with, but learning to use BeautifulSoup for this will also give you the skills to scrape all kinds of HTML in the future.

Answer (score 0):

First get list of html strings, To get that follow this [Convert BeautifulSoup4 HTML Table to a list of lists, iterating over each Tag elements](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154659/convert-beautifulsoup4-html-table-to-a-list-of-lists-iterating-over-each-tag-el)

Then perform following operation in that,

This will fetch you all values of elements you desire !

```
 for element in html_list:
    output = soup.select(element)[0].text
    print("%s ," % output)
```

This will give you what you desires,

Hope that helps !